# Video encoding by servlet with MEncoder

Tags: java, servlets, runtime, video-processing

I was developing an application for video encoding on the server and got a problem with encoding video with MEncoder. This decoder doesn't work correctly when runned by a command line with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“D:\mencoder\mnc\mencoder.exe  video1.avi -o outvideo1.flv -of lavf -oac mp3lame -lameopts abr:br=64 -srate 22050 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:vbitrate=300:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:cbp:last_pred=3 -vf scale=320:240,harddup -quiet”) ;
```

The decoder launches and works in windows console with my parameters, but when it's run from a servlet it just hangs in process list and doesn't do anything before the web-server is stopped. When trying to use decoder from a simple java applcation, it runs correctly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bad way to do this.  In general, mencoder will take much longer than users will be willing to wait.  Also, if mencoder leaks memory or crashes you risk taking down the whole jvm.  You also have no control over how many of these processes get spawned.  A better solution is to have a jms queue, or a database that you insert into.  Then you have another batch job that picks those up and processes those videos.  If you use the database approach, you can update the database as things progress, and keep the user up to date with progress stats.  In general keep this kind of runtime execution out of your web application container.

Comment: In this case, the user's expectations is not so critical. This process will be executed automatically when a sufficient amount of data. Assume When you have a certain number of users who require a low or high quality video, then video will be converted from the original in the desired bitrate, and provided to users for viewing or downloading. In this case, the main problem is the failure for unknown reasons Mencoder application.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because MPlayer outputs a lot of stuff in the terminal and as soon as it's output reaches 4096 bytes ( pipe buffer limit on Linux ) the process hangs on the next printf until some data is read on the other side of the pipe. And in your case it hangs forever as you are not reading standart output and error streams.
In order to get around this you can just close these streams as soon as you launch your process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“D:\mencoder\mnc\mencoder.exe  video1.avi -o outvideo1.flv -of lavf -oac mp3lame -lameopts abr:br=64 -srate 22050 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:vbitrate=300:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:cbp:last_pred=3 -vf scale=320:240,harddup -quiet”) ;
p.getInputStream().close();
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.getErrorStream().close();
```